# Riemann Integrable -- Is this true?

Tags: uniform-continuity

I have a sequence of functions $f_n$ (on a compact interval) which uniformly converge to $f$, and I know $f$ is Riemann Integrable. Is it true that $f_n$ must also be Riemann Integrable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $f$ be your favorite bounded, non Riemann integrable function and $f_n=f/n$.

Comment: Why $f$ non Riemann integrable?

Comment: This is a counterexample. Since $f$ is not Riemann integrable, none of the $f_n$ is, but $f_n$ converges uniformly to the constant function $0$, which is Riemann integrable.

Comment: The confusion comes from the notation. @Julián Aguirre: Maybe you should use a $g$ instead of an $f$, since $f$ shall be the limit function in Eddie's question.

Comment: Thank you, that helps clear it up.